# Semantic UI React : <thead> cannot appear as a child of <tbody>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am working on Semantic UI React Table. I get an error `<thead> cannot appear as a child of <tbody>`. Why is that?

```
<Table fixed>
  <Table.Header>
    <Table.Row>
      <Table.HeaderCell>Company Name</Table.HeaderCell>
      <Table.HeaderCell>Primary Phone</Table.HeaderCell>
    </Table.Row>
  </Table.Header>
  <Table.Body>
    <Table.Header>
      <Table.Row>
        <Table.HeaderCell>
          <Search />
        </Table.HeaderCell>
      </Table.Row>
    </Table.Header>
    <Table.Row>
      <Table.Cell>Apple</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>58895895</Table.Cell>
    </Table.Row>
  </Table.Body>
</Table>
```

It happen when I include this code:

```
<Table.Header>
  <Table.Row>
    <Table.HeaderCell>
      <Search />
    </Table.HeaderCell>
  </Table.Row>
</Table.Header>
```

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what's wrong. `<tbody><thead>...` is not allowed. Within the `<table>` tag, there should be first a `<thead>...</thead>` and then a `<tbody>...</tbody>` as sibling.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your issue is the `<Table.Header>` following `<Table.Body>`. Change your code to the following:

```
<Table fixed>
  <Table.Header>
    <Table.Row>
      <Table.HeaderCell>Company Name</Table.HeaderCell>
      <Table.HeaderCell>Primary Phone</Table.HeaderCell>
    </Table.Row>
  </Table.Header>
  <Table.Body>
    <Table.Row>
      <Table.HeaderCell>
        <Search />
      </Table.HeaderCell>
    </Table.Row>
    <Table.Row>
      <Table.Cell>Apple</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>58895895</Table.Cell>
    </Table.Row>
  </Table.Body>
</Table>
```